# 17.10 - 100% CPU Load almost all the time

Tags: 17.10, performance, systemd-journald

I am currently testing Ubuntu (17.10) and have almost all of the time 100% CPU load. I don’t think I can do anything against the `systemd-journald`, `gdb` or `rsyslogd` processes.

My specs (obtained from *Settings > Details > About*):

- 3.8 GiB memory
- Intel® Pentium(R) CPU B980 @ 2.40GHz × 2
- AMD Turks (Graphics)
- Gnome 3.26.2
- OS type 64bit
- DISK 487.0 GB

I can use the system but it is very slow. Sometimes it freezes completely, so I have to use the REISUB-Key combination (as described in [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)). My laptop gets hot relatively fast, so could this be the source of the problem?

Is there anything else I can check / do?

[image: top -n1 and system monitor]

Comment: Why are you running `gdb`?

Comment: This doesn't fix the freeze problem, but you have to divide top's CPU% by 8 for a quad core CPU and divide by 4 for a dual core CPU when hyper-threading is enabled: https://askubuntu.com/questions/842210/cpu-on-ubuntu-running-high/842214#842214

Comment: Clearly some process is logging like mad and that is causing the high cpu usage. `gdb` maybe?

Comment: IDK why systemd-journal is hogging so much CPU, but as a temporary solution, maybe you could change the niceness value. This value is basically a CPU priority: the higher the niceness, the lower priority the program gets. If you type `sudo renice -19 $(pgrep systemd-journal)`, that should give other programs the priority, which might help things for now. Hopefully someone else will be able to give you a more permanent solution. (You can also use top to change the niceness by pressing "r".)

Comment: As a temporary workaround You can try to disable the service `sudo systemctl disable systemd-journal.service` until You figure out what may trigger the excessive logging.

Comment: @Jos I though its a system process, dont know which program started gdb (visual studio code / monodevelop?)

Comment: @devius Dont think though, justs started my laptop and checked top -n1 -> there is no gdb but systemd-journal is again on 100%. Is the problem maybe related to ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: @TSJNachos117: after typing in the command to the terminal the %cpu value is between 90~100%.

Comment: @Michal Przybylowicz: Iam unable to get this command working. Says "Failed to disable unit: Unit file systemd-journal.service does not exist." After tab-completion there are only two service-files: systemd-resolved.service and systemd-timesyncd.service

Comment: Any errors on `dmesg` or `sudo journalctl -f`?

Comment: The command wouldn't really lower how much CPU journald is using. Rather, it would make sure that other programs have higher-priority access to the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Just experienced this situation myself.  One of the comments above was instrumental in helping me understand the root cause of the issue; namely that the cause for `systemd-journald` and `rsyslogd` to eat CPU is typically because another process is going crazy with logging.

In my case, `systemd-journald` was burning 100% of one core but I couldn't even stop it (`systemctl stop systemd-journald.service` just hung and a `kill -9` would just respawn a new instance, still eating up 100% of a core).  So I checked under `/var/log` and sure enough `syslog` had ballooned by over 600 MB in a matter of under 3 hours.  A quick `tail -f` revealed the culprit (`gnome-software` in this instance).  Killing that process immediately spun down the CPU.

Comment: In my case it was VLC running amok with log messages about an unsupported gamma filter. 
I had left VLC open on Ubuntu 20.04 laptop with a video paused, and let it sit there for a few days. I only noticed because I thought my fans were spinning higher than usual, and it was time for a (physical dust) cleaning cycle.
It had produced over 600 GB of log entries on one of my 1TB nvme drives. I had to close VLC and delete all the syslog* files. I used `truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog` on the main file, as I'm not sure if the system needs it to exist (probably).

Comment: @Henrik ___600 GB___ ????????????!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!?!? OH MY GOD